# Spacing between HTML text and Font Awesome icon

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, font-awesome

I am trying to insert a font awesome icon before a text inside a paragraph, however when I reproduce it as a smartphone, the icon gotten mixed with text. If I put padding/margin or something like this, on smartphone view it got great but on desktop icon got so far of text. How can I make the smartphone get like the desktop view without change the last one?

Here is some idea about the code:

```
<header>
  <h1>This is a text <br> reference <b>33131</b></h1>
  <h3>Something Here</h2>
  <p>
    <b class="b_title">Field:</b>
    <br>
    Something Here
  </p>
  <p>
    <b class="b_title">Field:</b>
    <br>
    <i class="fas fa-compass fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i> Something Here
  </p>
  <p>
    <b class="b_title">Field:</b>
    <br>
    <i class="fas fa-compass fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i> Something Here
  </p>
  <p>
    <b class="b_title">Field:</b>
    <br>
    <i class="far fa-calendar fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i> Something Here
  </p>
  <p>
    <b class="b_title">Field:</b>
    <br>
    <i class="far fa-clock fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i> Something Heredays
  </p>
</header>

<ul class="progress">
  {% for move in object.moves %}
    {% if loop.first %}
      <li class="progress__item progress__item--active">
    {% else %}
      <li class="progress__item progress__item--completed">
    {% endif %}
      <p class="progress__info"><i class="far fa-calendar fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i><b>Something Here</b></p>
      <p class="progress__info"><i class="fas fa-compass fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i><b>Something Here</b></p>
      <p class="progress__info"><b>Field:</b> Something Info Here</p>
      <p class="progress__info"><b>Field:</b> Something Info Here</p>
      <p class="progress__info"><b>Field:</b> Something Info Here</p>
      <p></p>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aipim/5q978fym/

How I am using Jinja2 it will not compile. But below I insert the images to a better understanding.

Desktop version:
[image]

Mobile version:
[image]

Comment: There might be a case when `fa` applying some specific styles for mobile. Can you copy-paste your html (from browser) to jsfiddle to demonstrate the issue live? So it should be just css and html w/o any processors.

Comment: @extempl Excellent idea! Done. Please, can you see again?

Comment: To test it, try to use Google Chrome mobile view, like I did in second image. I do not know why, but on desktop view independently of width, it sounds nice.

Comment: The result page on any mobile view also looks good: https://fiddle.jshell.net/aipim/5q978fym/show/

Comment: Same for browsing on mobile:https://photos.app.goo.gl/9puYyNWLhcUVt1g89. So that's probably some css you using in dev mode (or even some js script which runs on resize or something).

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of time thinking and reading about it, I asked help to a friend who discovered that it happens because is necessary to use the viewport meta tag in the header.

```
<meta
  name="viewport"
  content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
 />
```

Finally, it worked! When I created my example on jsfiddle, my template must have inherited from its header.

Answer (score 0):

You can add Media Query for your mobile device, which will not affect your desktop version,

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  p.progress__info i{margin-right:10px;}
}
```

Comment: I updated jsfiddle as @extempl requested with source page. Now is better to test. I tried to apply your suggestion but unfortunately, it did not work. Do you have any other suggestion my friend?

Comment: I tried to look at your fiddle, but it just shows bunch of letters, can't test anything there.try to paste the browser rendered html there, not your server side coding

Comment: Oh shit! :/ It didn't save. Can you look again? Now I think that saved.

Comment: It is not saving. I will create another.

Comment: seems fine isn't it? I tried in width 413px  https://pasteboard.co/I8zicJ3.png and one with 329px here https://pasteboard.co/I8ziL1K.png

Comment: Try create a .html and .css and use mobile view on chrome console like I did in my second image. I do not know why but on browser it sounds nice with any width.

Comment: if you have a online version of your site/page which I can test, please let me know so I can see the problem at first hand

Comment: Thank for your time. I resolved it! Please, see my answer to get the solution.